# Swift 2.0 Type '()' does not conform to protocol

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm implementing this method while using the camera in a `view controller`

```
let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

//... code
if let device = captureDevice {
            do {
                if (try device.lockForConfiguration()) {
                    device.focusPointOfInterest = focusPoint
                    device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.ContinuousAutoFocus
                    device.exposurePointOfInterest = focusPoint
                    device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.ContinuousAutoExposure
                    device.unlockForConfiguration()
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Error")
            }
        }
//... code
```

Trying to convert to `Swift 2.0` I found this error `Type '()' does not conform to protocol to 'BooleanType'` at line

```
if (try device.lockForConfiguration())
```

Actually I'm trying to figure out how to solve this, how can I make this a `'BooleanType'`? In `Swift 1.2` my code was simply

```
if (device.lockForConfiguration())
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks that lockForConfiguration returns Void and throws, so return value does not conform to BooleanType.

I think that the following code should work for you:

```
if let device = captureDevice {
    do {
        try device.lockForConfiguration()
        device.focusPointOfInterest = focusPoint
        device.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.ContinuousAutoFocus
        device.exposurePointOfInterest = focusPoint
        device.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.ContinuousAutoExposure
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. I just realised if the `try` statement will fail it'll skip to the `catch` not executing code, otherwise will continue normally.